# Getting identity document updated after verification Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am having issues getting an account verified on Stripe. This account was previusly verified, but due to latest guidelines , it had to give in SSN number.

However, I have been trying to upload ID number(SSN), but it is not getting verified. I suspect, its because the Identity Document needs to be changed as well.

The right approach here seems to use API to re-upload the document. Can someone please guide me on on this. I have my Stripe key, Users SSn and Identity document with me.

I do see an API, but i am not sure if i should use it, since it is a critical account.
Secondly, am not sure whihc of these 2 should be updated?

[![Error message][1]][1]

````
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_wsIteSi2J2OE0UivD0tzS5aw'

Stripe::Account.update_person(
  '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  '{{PERSON_ID}}',
  {verification: {document: {front: 'file_5dtoJkOhAxrMWb'}}},
)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPXP.png
````

Comment: Your general approach of uploading the file and attaching it to the person or account is generally correct (as mentioned in https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#handling-identity-verification), but if you're worried about the process at all you'll probably want to talk to Stripe's support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact) to get more help instead of asking here.

Comment: Yes, that's one approach. There is another approach too, which basically uploading the image in my Candidate model . However, once i get done, can you suggest me how to push the updated record to Stripe?

Comment: I'm assuming the Candidate model is something you have built off a Stripe Account/Person - you'd push the updated record by mapping the updated fields back to what they relate to on the Stripe Account/Person and then updating those through the API